# Display tab contents - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, division, display

I am working with a JS function where I have a tabbed panel and each tab opens a division within the same HTML file. I've set the first tab's to be displayed by default(these contents will be active as the page loads). But when I try clicking the second tab my specified tab's contents don't get displayed.

**HTML Forms that are displayed under each tab**

> First Tab's contents are under the division `addRequest` division

```
<div id="addRequest" class="tabcontent">

<div id="form_container">

<!--<h1><a>Acquisition</a></h1>-->
<form id="form_1147240" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
    <div class="form_description">
        <h2>Acquisition</h2>
        <p>Enter the details of the material required</p>
    </div>
    <ul >

        <div id="leftDiv" style="float: left; width: 50%;" >

            <!--Material Type-->

            <li id="li_7" >
                <label class="description" for="element_7">Material Type </label>
                <div class = "listItems">
                    <select class="element select medium" id="element_7" name="element_7">
                        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                        <option value="1" >Books</option>
                        ...
```

[image: Tab 1 contents]

> Second Tab's contents are under the division `addNewMaterial` division

```
<div id="addNewMaterial" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="form_container1">
        <form id="form_11472401" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
            <div class="form_description">
                <h2>Acquisition</h2>
                <p>Enter the details of the new material</p>
            </div>
            <ul >

                <div id="leftDiv1" style="float: left; width: 50%;" >

                    <!--Material Type-->

                    <li id="li_71" >
                        <label class="description" for="element_71">Material Type </label>
                        <div class = "listItems">
                            <select class="element select medium" id="element_71" name="element_71">
                                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value="1" >Books</option>
```

[image: Contents are not displayed for tab 2]

**Tab Section**

```
<body>

<ul class="tab">
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'addRequest')">Add Request</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'addNewMaterial')">New Materials</a></li>
 </ul>
<div id="addRequest" class="tabcontent">
<div id="form_container">
```

**JS Function**

```
function openTab(evt, divisionId) {
// Declare all variables
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

// Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}

// Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}

// Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
document.getElementById(divisionId).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the css of the second tab content with the browser inspector (F12)? Apart of invalid html, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: While inspecting as you mentioned, the addNewMaterial division was embedded within the addRequest division. Hence when setting the addRequest division's display property to none and addNewMaterials division's display property to show the block the property was being overidden and not diplaying both. THANKS A MILLION for the suggestion. Got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the below code in your java-script code. I am trying to create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3s0ar44/) using your code. Sorry for bad formating in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3s0ar44/), but you can see the output window is working fine. check out my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3s0ar44/)

```
document.getElementById('addRequest').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('addNewMaterial').style.display = "none";
```

Comment: The problem was with the tags being embedded within each other. And the second tab was overridden by the first one's display property. Thanks anyway